# I want to be a hero: fire-proof

Tags: society, super-powers

Something I love is creative use of simple superpowers, so I'd thought I ask a for help coming up with the foundations of a character I've been stuck on.

Basically, their sole super power is an immunity to temperature changes.

Regardless of outside factors or exertion, this individual's body temperature remains at a uniform 70 degrees Fahrenheit (21 Celsius). This should make them clinically dead, but their biological functions are miraculously and physics-breakingly normal.

Not only is their body temperature unusual, but even the most extremes of heat and cold don't phase them. They could be laying on the north pole or sprinting through the Sahara without any changes to the amount of water they need to drink or clothes they need to wear. Burning and frost-burning are impossible, but other means of injury and death are totally viable. Smoke inhalation and starvation, for example are both still fatal.

With all that in mind, *could this person become an hero, or a superhero?* It doesn't have to be an all-powerful superheoic figure, like Superman; smaller tasks of heroism or good-old-plain generosity are welcome too.

In other words: *how could this person use the fire-proof ability to do good?* While donating 20% of his net income to charity would be kind, it doesn't concern us here for the scope of the question.

Assume that a secret identity isn't required. If anyone wants to examine how this person would fare in superhuman combat, by all means feel free.

Comment: "what could this person do to perform the most good in the world?" is material for a book. Or a series of books. Thus, I voted too broad.

Comment: `:s/phase/faze/` "Phase" is a Greek word, which in English has various, mostly scientific, meanings; the basic meaning being "a specific point in a cycle". "Faze" is a good old Germanic word, meaning "to frighten". (Wiktionary says that even Mark Twain made the mistake of confusing the two words; so you are in good company. The rule of thumb is that "ph" pronounced "f" almost always indicates Greek ancestry, and thus marks the word as most likely a scientific or philosophical term.)

Comment: I've edited the question (mainly in the last paragraph) to make it less broad. I hope it can be un-holded.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, he can help recover the bodies of all those who have died climbing Mount Everest. That would pretty good for the families of those who didn't make it, because its just way to expensive and risky to send people up there just to recover a body.

He would also make a good firefighter or arctic rescuer which would be helpful. Since he isn't affected by the heat or the cold, he doesn't need to pack the same protective clothing that other normal people might need and can instead carry more equipment or supplies (e.g. more oxygen or more food) meaning he could stay in those conditions a bit longer than a normal person.

They would also be great for the scientific community. Not researching him, but getting samples from locations where its simply to hot to operate or too cold to. Some examples could be near or in volcanoes or vents.

A more realistic version would be that he does the above and uses that to start or fund a charity. That wayhe could impact more people than he could reach by himself. There is a limit to how much good a single person can do, and creating an organization using your name and fame is a good way to enlarge the impact you can have.

Finally, a bit more darker... You could harvest his skin and hair to create the perfect insulating material. Skin already flakes off, and you lose hair naturally, so you can collect those. They would make dangerous things, like Re-entry very interesting, because they don't conduct heat, so if you wrap a shuttle in his skin, it wouldn't heat up the inside of it. Assuming you could harvest some of his hair follicles or get some cells, you could probably start growing parts of his body and cloning him, providing you with more insulator materials.It would also be pretty useful in science, but I don't know too much about that.

Of course, you might want to say that his power only works when its on him, but we are basically covered with a layer of dead skin which protects us, so unless you want part of his skin melting or freezing off after a long day of exposure it should work.

Comment: The Lack of Oxygen on Everest will be as fatal to him as the climbers that died there, yes they died of hypothermia or falling not just lack of oxygen, but he would need to be up there a lot longer to located and safely reach them to begin the recovery. The Re-entry idea is an interesting one though

Answer (score 1):

Start a religion, use said powers as proof of God's love and direct followers to help people instead of buying mansions, sports cars and private jets

Seriously your powers aren't going to do much. With fire, it's the smoke and lack of oxygen that kills you. Rescuing people in a snow storm, it's the lack of visibility that stops you.

As for superhuman combat, buy a gun. For the small handful of heroes that you have an advantage, it'll come down to a fist fight.

Answer (score -1):

They could perform rescue missions on high or low-temperature environments such as industrial fire (assuming they have appropriate breathing gear) or Antarctic rescue missions. With regards to fighting, dousing themselves in gas or oil and immolating themselves (since you said they can't die of burning) would be effective or releasing a quick freeze chemical like liquid nitrogen to inflict cold damage.

If your tech allows for it, they can also encase themselves in either fire or ice armor (certain parts only for ice) for protection and elemental damage or maybe a liquid-metal like substance ala Terminator's T-1000 that only people who are impervious to temperature changes can wear because it generates extreme cold and/or heat depending on what you want it to do.

Comment: Why the downvote? I've answered the OP's question including how the person with this power can fight and the answer above is similar to mine too and I posted first.